# Commuting matrices share the same eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question has been already answered. If A and B are diagonalizable matrices, then AB=BA if AND only if they share the same set of eigenvectors. However, the only if part does not need the diagonalization hypothesis. For example, taking
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}, \quad B=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix},
$$
clearly we have that $A$ and $B$ are not diagonalizable but they share the same eigenvectors and obviously they commute. So I suspect that the diagonalization hypothesis is not necessary in order to prove that if two matrices share the same set of eigenvectors then they commute. Any hint to prove this fact without the hypothesis of diagonalization would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that if $A,B$ share the same invariant subspace for each of its jordan block $A,B$ will commute, no matter the eigenvalue for the jordan block

Answer (score 1):

We can prove that two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ commute if they share the same eigenvectors. Although this requires that we have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. This can we proved under the hypothesis that $A$ have $n$ distinct eigenvalues and $B$ has the same eigenvectors as $A$. This is because we need that there are $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors and having $n$ distinct eigenvalues guarantees that there are $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors as eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent.

But even if eigenvalues are not distinct, the eigenvectors can still be linearly independent(although this won't always be the case). As a simple example, consider the identity matrix with the same eigenvalues but the corresponding eigenvectors are linearly independent. Thus we can change our hypothesis from having $n$ distinct eigenvalues to just being that $A$ have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors and $B$ having the same eigenvectors as $A$. Of course the case where $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues and shares the same eigenvectors, the same result holds.

Proposition: Let $A, B\in F^{n,n}$ such that $A$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors and $B$ has the same eigenvectors as $A$. Then we have that $AB=BA$.

Proof: Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be the eigenvectors of $A$. Given that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, these eigenvectors form a basis. Thus, to show that $AB=BA$, it suffices to show that $(AB)v_i=(BA)v_i$. Let $\lambda_1,\dots\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues(possible repeating) corresponding to the eigenvectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $A$ and let $c_1,\dots,c_n$ be the eigenvalues(possibly repeating) corresponding to the eigenvectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $B$. Then we have $$(AB)v_i=A(Bv_i)=A(c_iv_i)$$ $$=c_i(Av_i)=c_i\lambda_iv_i=\lambda_ic_iv_i=(BA)v_i$$

Thus, $AB=BA$.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No, merely sharing the same set of eigenvectors isn't sufficient to guarantee commutativity.  The set of eigenvectors of both
\begin{align}
A&=\pmatrix{2&1&0\\
         0&2&0\\
         0&0&1}\ \ \ \ \text{ and}\\
B&=\pmatrix{2&0&0\\
         0&1&0\\
         0&1&1}\\
\end{align}
is
$$
\left\{\left.\pmatrix{\lambda\\0\\0},\pmatrix{0\\0\\\mu}\right|\,\lambda\ne0,\mu\ne0\right\}\ .
$$
However,
\begin{align}
AB&=\pmatrix{4&\color{red}{1}&0\\0&2&0\\0&\color{red}{1}&1}\ \ \ \ \text{, whereas}\\
BA&=\pmatrix{4&\color{red}{2}&0\\0&2&0\\0&\color{red}{2}&1}\ .
\end{align}
As Binxu Wang's comment makes clear, however, there's at least one hypothesis that's weaker than the diagonalisation hypothesis, and which, together with that of  sharing the same set of eigenvectors, will be sufficient to guarantee commutativity.